# XML converted to JSON with AngularJS, how to render the result with leading '@' on values?

Tags: xml, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-ng-repeat

[image: This is the result returned from the POST calculation]

1. Here's the front end display and I've tried writing out {{calcs.@city}} which blows up with AngularJS errors so it doesn't appear to like the @ symbol.

   ```
        </div>
             <div class="col-sm-12">
                 <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="calcs in calculations">
                           {{calcs}}
                     </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
        </div>
   ```

How do I display the data with AngularJS since the response contains the '@' symbol as an attribute from the XML that is generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the square bracket notation:

```
<li ng-repeat="calcs in calculations">
  {{ calcs['@city'] }}
</li>
```

For clarity - this is essentially a Javascript issue. Square bracket notation allows access to properties containing special characters.